# GStreamer: Dynamically removing mixer src element freezes pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, vala

I am trying to mix audio using gstaudiomixer from two source elements that I add and remove dynamically.

```
+---------+    +------------+
| source1 |--->|            |
+---------+    |            |    +-----------+
               | audiomixer |--->| audiosink |
+---------+    |            |    +-----------+
| source2 |--->|            |
+---------+    +------------+
```

Dynamically adding elements (using request pads and pad templates) seems to work as intended.
However, when dynamically removing a pad causes the pipeline to freeze.

This was the code I used to remove the element:

```
public void remove(Gst.Element? element)
{
    /* Removes the element from the pipeline */
    if (element == null) return;

    element.set_state(Gst.State.NULL);  // Stop it from streaming data
    element.unlink(this.mixer);
    this.pipeline.remove(element);
}
```

This is my second attempt, trying to block the pad:

```
public void remove(Gst.Element? element)
{
    /* Removes the element from the pipeline */
    if (element == null) return;

    element.get_static_pad("src").get_peer().add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.IDLE, (pad, info) => {
        element.set_state(Gst.State.NULL);  // Stop it from streaming data
        element.unlink(this.mixer);
        this.pipeline.remove(element);
        return Gst.PadProbeReturn.REMOVE;
    });
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change or remove a element from the pipeline, make sure you stop pushing  buffers to the element, send an eos to the element and add a new one and proceed. Its well explained in this [link](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html#changing-elements-in-a-pipeline)